# Fixed-size array of objects initialization order in C++/MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, visual-studio-2015

I have a class definitions in my project, that resembles something like this:

```
class A { std::map<type> some_map; };

class B { A array_of_a[10]; std::map<type> some_map; };

class C { B array_of_b[15]; std::map<type> some_map; };

class D { C array_of_c[5]; std::map<type> some_map; };

class E { D d; };
```

It compiles in MSVC without any errors or warnings, but when I try to run my program where I try to create on my stack an object of class **E**, *sometimes* (like 50% of my runs) I get weird "access violation writing" exceptions from either std::map, or from other STL types like mutex that I use inside class **E**, that being thrown during one of the above classes constructor invocations.

I didn't create any explicit threads in my program, this code just runs from a regular **main()**, but the non-deterministic nature of this bug gives me a feeling like MSVC did some behind-the-scenes optimization for me, and decided to do some kind of weird non-serialized initialization for me.

What actually happening here and what am I doing wrong in my code? Is it wrong to initialize static-sized arrays of objects that contain STL class fields?

Comment: I guess we can tell nothing unless you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW, why do you call it _static_, if you create them on stack?

Comment: You need to supply a more specific example.  You've used the word "static" in the title but stack in the description

Comment: Are you allocating only one instance of `E` or maybe several? In a recursive function? Do you have other big objects on the stack? Are those **all** the members of A,B,C,D and E? You mention a mutex, but I don't see any in `E`. Are there other big objects on the stack? PS. there is no mutex in STL. I think you mean the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no guarantee as to the order that the initializers will be run. This is known as the "static initialization order fiasco": https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

There's some good info at that link, but the short version is that you'll need to structure your code such that the object get initialized or constructed when you first use it. That way you can guarantee the order they get initialized by the order you use them in your code.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer, but it's the right one.  Ryan's faster than me! :-) http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html  The solution is covered right after the description in the link I gave and involves construction on first use

Comment: Where have you guys seen that it is static? OP says: "I try to create on my stack..." I believe OP just uses "static" word in a wrong way: "Is it wrong to initialize static-sized arrays..."

Comment: @Petr "Static allocated object array initialization order in C++/MSVC" is the title, I made assumptions.

Comment: I meant "static" in term that all arrays that I described above have fixed size known at compilation time, and haven't been dynamically allocated by the use of "new", "malloc", or anything similar.

And object of class E is just created on stack by a regular "E e_object;" line in the main()

Comment: That's what I supposed: @user1483597 just uses the term "static" in a wrong way.